# Program will not run for larger values in tens and hundred except floating

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a program to solve the problem of changed owed after a customer purchases goods.

The changes are meant to be mostly in floating variable like 0.50 for 50cents and that works fine but for situation where the change owed are in whole number like 10 and 9 the program will not carry out necessary operations

I have converted the input from float to input but to no avail

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int change(void);
int main()
{
    float num;
    int y;
    int counter = 0;
    do
    {
     num = get_float("Change owed: ");
     num = round(num * 100);
     y = (int) num;
     printf("%d\n", y);

    }
    while(num <= 0);
    while(y>0)
    {
        if(y > 25)
        {
            y-=25;

            counter++;
        }
        else if(y < 25 && y >= 10)
        {
            y-=10;

            counter++;
        }
        else if(y < 10 && y >= 5)
        {
            y-=5;

            counter++;
        }
          else if(y < 5 && y >= 1)
        {
            y-=1;

            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;    
        }

    }
    printf("%d \n", counter);

}
```

I want to be able to run the program for all numeric data types

Comment: What if `y` is equal to 25?

Comment: Print a message instead of `return 0;`. For instance, `printf("%d\n", y);` will lead you straight to the bug.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Don't tag both "just in case" or because they look similar to you. As far as I know, CS50 is a C course.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program with failing input, what observations did you make? This is exactly what a debugger is for: to run your program one line at a time, inspect the values of all variables as they change and observe your program's logical flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. No exceptions. You have a few simple bugs, and using a debugger you should be able to figure them out all by yourself. Don't you think it's better to be able to find and fix your own bugs, with a debugger, than post a question here, and wait?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. just wanted something that would lead me or help spot the mistake.

Comment: @user4581301: Immediately after getting the input, which the assignment may necessitate doing with `get_float`, the program converts to a number of cents in an `int` and then does the remaining work with integer arithmetic. Do you fail to notice this when you wrote your suggestion?

Comment: I think you're missing a case for y >= 100.

Comment: @molbdnilo: In this case both tags are fine because the integer and floating point rules are identical.

Comment: @Joshua But if this was C++ people should be telling the OP to use C++ I/O and C++ standard library headers instead of the C `.h` headers.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang: Use of C++ I/O instead of printf is a style debate in this case.

Comment: Please am very sorry I tagged c++ earlier. forgive me

Comment: Thanks everyone once again. it has been dealt with.https://submit.cs50.io/users/darothub/cs50/problems/2019/x/cash

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP solved the problem and the rest of us still don't understand it.